# Unable to display image on Android using imageview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, layout-inflater

I have gone through every tutorial to display an image on an android phone from a URL. I am trying to bind an imageview object to the HTTP url but I keep getting a unable to inflate imageview class error:

> 02-16 23:32:50.204: E/AndroidRuntime(499): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.DBResults/com.DBResults.ContactView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class Imageview

Theo code in my java file:

```
 ....
 setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1); 
 imageView.setImageDrawable(createDrawableFromURL("http://savagelook.com/misc/sl_drop2.png"));
 ....
 private Drawable createDrawableFromURL(String urlString) {
    Drawable image = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    InputStream is = (InputStream)url.getContent();
    image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // handle URL exception
    image = null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle InputStream exception
    image = null;
}

return image;
}
```

My XML file looks like this (line 82 is the opening imageview tag):

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" android:background="@drawable/white">
    <Imageview  android:id="@+id/ImageView1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" /> 
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a typo. it should be ImageView!

Comment: Huang I deliberately named the imageview object: ImageView1 and not ImageView!

Comment: @RohanPereira No, I mean, in you xml file, you declared a ImageView widget, but you mistype it as `Imageview`, it should be `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent so many days trying so many different things..  You are truly amazing.

Comment: @RohanPereira Welcome to StackOverflow. If my answer is right, you may want to accept it(by clicking the 'tick' at the left side of my answer) or up-vote it(by clicking the upper arrow). This will encourage more people to answer the questions in the future.